# Regexp match whole word not using \b

Tags: javascript, regex

I don't want to use `\b` because `str. abc` matches the `str`

**I want to match `str` when:**

- It is the sorounded in white spaces. Ex: "abc str xyz"
- It is at the begining/end of a sentence. Ex: "str abc" and "abc str"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/(?:^| )(str)(?:$| )/
```

match "start of line or space" followed by "str" followed by "end of line or space".  Replace the spaces with `\s` if you also want to match tab characters.

Comment: I didn't know \s matched tabs, I guess it is true one learns something every day

Answer (score 6):

The following should work:

```
(?:^|\s)(str)(?:$|\s)
```

Here is the breakdown:

```
(?:^|\s)   # match either the beginning of the string or whitespace
(str)      # match 'str' and place it into capture group 1
(?:$|\s)   # match either the end of the string or whitespace
```

An alternative would be to use lookbehind/lookahead which would be nice because you wouldn't need to use a capture group, but I don't think that js supports lookbehind.

Comment: I'd consider up-voting, but I'd need you to explain what the various regex options actually *mean*...

Comment: @DavidThomas - I was already in the process of editing to add explanation.

Comment: Well, you wouldn't be the first to suggest I'm premature... =/ Oh, and +1 =)

Comment: I wrote this exact expression just last week!